# Why is PHP's cURL is prefixing HTTP headers with "HTTP_"?

Tags: php, http, curl, header

I am sending the http header `X-SSID`, but server receives it as `HTTP_X_SSID`.
I'm using cURL but it's not required; I just need to send this header by post method and get content.

Here's [the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKsxC.jpg) I'm using to make the request:

```php
$ch = curl_init();

// ... other setup code; see link above for full context)

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, arrat(
  "X-SSID: {$ssid}",
  "X-API_VERSION: 2"
});

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($ssid, $server_output);
curl_close($ch);
```

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXGwN.jpg) how the server sees the request:

```
["HTTP_X_SSID"]=>
string(32) "[truncated]"
["HTTP_X_API_VERSION"]=>
string(1) "2"
```

Comment: can you post the code you use to send this curl request?

Comment: @wodka, https://imgur.com/a/4DsV53A

Comment: and why do you now think that HTTP_X_SSID is sent to the server?

Comment: @wodka i sent once request to my server and checked it https://imgur.com/ol0zLwO

Comment: ah :) then please check my answer - this is just how received headers are exposed in php

Comment: Updated to show the code the user is using and the response from the server

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking the headers in php please note that they are exposed like this.

ie sending X-test will produce a global var $HTTP_X_TEST

Comment: ok that's confirming that problem with headers isn't in my script